# Rotate screen without turn on auto-rotate

Tags: android, rotation, autorotate

I'm making a small streaming TV application for Android.

I want to set the video-view to fullscreen when the user rotates its device. But it was only allowed when Auto-rotate button was enabled.

How to make the app rotate the screen without turning on the auto-rotate button? I noticed that there are many apps and games that can do that, like Clash Of Clan.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your AndroidManifest add this attribute to your Activity  : 
 `android:screenOrientation="landscape"`

else add this code into onCreate Method :
 
`this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE);`
it will make it rotate as soon as it run 
hope that helps you

Comment: Actually it should be `android:screenOrientation="sensor"`